# Executing a command in every x-session

Tags: xorg

How can I execute an arbitrary command for every x-session (belonging to any
user)? 
(At any time, not just on login.)

Comment: My guess would be a script in `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/` but I'm not 100% on this.

Comment: @arcsin You are correct! If you want to throw that in an answer you'd have my upvote. Scripts in `xinitrc.d` get run when an xsession is started. It's a perfect way to add `xhost` rules as an example (and is how the logged in user gets `xhost` rules allowing them to use their `xsession` normally).

Comment: @arcsin, sorry, I meant at any time, not just on login.